# Run specific project within solution in VS 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

I'm very inexperienced with Visual Studio.

I'm exploring the EmguCV example solution (see screencap below).  It has many subprojects.

[image: EmguCV Solution Explorer]

I opened the `HelloWorld` project and clicked `Start` from the toolbar.  The program ran and I closed it.  I'm assuming this set it as the "default" project, because it's now **bolded** in the Solution Explorer.

Now I want to run the `ImageDatabase` project.  When I open its `Program.cs` file, or its `MainForm.cs`, and click `Start`, *VS just runs `HelloWorld` again*.

**How do I change the default project that's run when I click `Start`?**

Comment: right-click project, select "Set at startup project"

Comment: Or right-click project, debug -> start new instance. Either of these work.

Comment: Both of those work.  First to put them in an answer gets an upvote and and an accept.

Comment: you're right @Adam, voted to close.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the project you want to run, click "set as startup project." Run the program as you would normally.